# Realm - Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lio/realm/DefaultRealmModule;

Tags: android, realm

I have created:

1) Library-A that uses Realm

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

and 2) Project-A that uses Realm and library-A; Project-A doesn't use Library-A's schema.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

main project's gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.3"
}
```

During build, I'm encountering these errors:

```
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lio/realm/DefaultRealmModule;
Error:Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lio/realm/DefaultRealmModuleMediator;
Error:2 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':x:transformClassesWithDexForDevDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Return code 1 for dex process
```

UPDATE: it seems that there's something wrong with my build setup, in further checks simply adding the plugin to the library resulted to the error.

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

What causes this error and how should I resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you expose the RealmObjects used by the library as a `@RealmModule`?

Comment: No. Is it required even when the project won't use the RealmObjects of library?

Comment: Apparently it is so that the Realm annotation processor knows that it is a library.

Answer (score 1):

Separate your models into modules.

Somewhere in library declare

```
// You can make this a singleton, annotations are the important part.
@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
class LibraryRealmModule {}
```

This will put all model classes within that library into `LibraryRealmModule`.

You can do the same thing in your app project but if you don't specify any modules a default module will be generated for you. This generated module will contain all model classes from the app project.

Then when you build the `Realm` instance provide the following configuration:

```
final LibraryRealmModule libRealmModule = new LibraryRealmModule();
final RealmConfiguration config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME) // Just a file name
        .modules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), libRealmModule) // List all modules
        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded() // TODO Actually migrate data when in production!
        .build()
final Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
```

Other than that your plugin config is correct.

Comment: This code assumes you'll use both library and app models from one realm. If the library uses a different realm from the app project you need to a) provide a different realm name b) still declare an explicit module in the library.

Comment: This is the correct solution, so something must be wrong in your build setup then if this doesn't work.

Comment: it seems that there's something wrong with my build setup, in further checks simply adding the apply plugin: 'realm-android' resulted to the error.

Answer (score 0):

On the project structure I had asked in this question, Eugen's answer doesn't directly fix the problem I've encountered, but he's correct that a RealmModule has to be created.

Another library, Library-B (RealModule) was created and contained both the RealmObjects of Library-A and Project-A. After setting it as dependency of the 2, only then the problem has been solved.